# Configurable password validator startup errors

Tags: django

I'm implementing a custom password validator that refers to settings in the database that an admin user can change.  A simplified example:

```
class ConfigurableMinimumLengthValidator(object):

  def get_value(self):
      return MyConfigModel.objects.first().password_minimum_length

  def validate(self, password, user=None):
      min_len = self.get_value()
      if len(password) < min_len:
          raise ValidationError("Password too short, must be > %s long." % min_len)

  def get_help_text(self):
      min_len = self.get_value()
      return "Password must be > %s long." % min_len
```

Django calls get_help_text() during its initial setup, which is roughly equivalent to making a database call during module import.  This causes all kinds of chicken-and-egg problems:

- If the MyConfigModel table doesn't exist yet, say on a new database, it raises an OperationalError.
- If the table exists but the password_minimum_length field doesn't exist, it raises a ProgrammingError.
- Finally, if the field exists but there are no rows in the table, that's a MyConfigModel.DoesNotExist exception.  That one is manageable.

The first two make it impossible to resolve without taking the password validator out of settings.py, as the error happens during `./manage.py migrate` and every other management command.

At first I planned to just catch these exceptions and return a default value; it'll query again during actual validation.  But I'm not sure I've thought of all of the possible exceptions and I don't want to use a bare except clause.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  Some lazy proxy string object that isn't evaluated until used?  Or a way to detect that Django is still setting up?  Monkey-patching the setup routine to not call get_help_text() until later?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an init function to your validator class, and pass the parameter to this function as an OPTIONS value in `settings.py`. The following example is from the Django 1.11 code for the MinimumLengthValidator in `django.contrib.auth.password_validation`. It passes `min_length` as a parameter:

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 15,
        }
    },
]
```

**password_validation.py**

```
class MinimumLengthValidator(object):
    """
    Validate whether the password is of a minimum length.
    """

    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if len(password) < self.min_length:
            raise ValidationError(
                ungettext(
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
                    self.min_length
                 ),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'min_length': self.min_length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return ungettext(
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
             self.min_length
        ) % {'min_length': self.min_length}
```

Django code from https://github.com/django/django
Copyright Django Software Foundation and individual contributors
SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

Comment: My settings are in the database, not the settings file.  They can be reconfigured at runtime.